# Check that a value is lower than a value in another table postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, constraints

```
CREATE TABLE Time(
Tipo VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY,
DataInizio DATE,
DataFine DATE NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO Time VALUES('PreIscrizione', '2017-02-01', '2017-04-30');
INSERT INTO Time VALUES('Candidatura', '2017-05-01', '2017-07-30');

CREATE TABLE PreIscrizione(
Studente VARCHAR(16) REFERENCES Persona ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE PRIMARY KEY,
DataPreIscrizione DATE CHECK(DataPreIscrizione<(SELECT DataFine FROM Time WHERE Tipo = 'PreIscrizione')));
```

The table PreIscrizione allows to sign up a student, but it has to be done before a date indicated in the table Time. Obviously what i wrote above doesn't work, but it explains my idea. Which is the right way to solve this?

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't allow subqueries in check constraints. Usually the same can be done with a Trigger or you use a Procedure to check before the insert.

Comment: I am studying triggers right now, i'll try to use it